# Variable is not passed to the remote machine

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to execute from the local machine to remote machine using ssh. i have set `$HN` and `$ManagedServerName` values - but when i execute the below command - `$ManagedServerName` variable is taking null value

```
ssh $HN 'echo `cd /u01/app/oracle/product/webcenter/sites; find -name "*.ini" -not -path "./Shared/*" -not -path ".logs/*" -exec sed -i 's/TWP/'$ManagedServerName'/g' {} \;
```

Please suggest,

Thanks

Comment: The backtick is not terminated.  Your sample command is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting is wrong.  The single quote before the echo is being closed by the first single quote in the sed expression, and then you open a new single quote around $ManagedServerName, so the shell on the other side is trying to expand that variable.  Try:

```
sed -i "s/TWP/'"$ManagedServerName"'/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use double quotes in your sed command so you can have proper variable expansion and concatenation to the search term:

```
ssh $HN 'echo `cd /u01/app/oracle/product/webcenter/sites; find -name "*.ini" -not -path "./Shared/*" -not -path ".logs/*" -exec sed -i "s/TWP/$ManagedServerName/g" {} \;
```

Comment: The remote machine is taking Null value to $ManagedServerName